# Clone object in Corel Draw to fill a page

Tags: coreldraw

I have a 5cmx9cm personal card and I want to fill an A3 page with clones of it.

Is there a simple way to do it than doing it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more ways to achieve this.

If you want to obtain a print or pdf with clones, you may use the printmenu. Go to the printpreview and use the imposition tool, left toolbar, second icon from above. Then put as many items on the page as you want.

The other option is to use the 'transform' menu: Alt+F7.